# What is the most suitable design pattern and architecture pattern for an online e-commerce application?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I'm developing an online food ordering system using php and mysql for an assignment.What will be the most suitable design pattern and architecture pattern for this web application?Could any one please explain me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and come back to edit your question to improve it

Comment: There is not _the_ pattern. Always a combination of design patterns to solve different problems. The moment you understand some of the design patterns you will understand that. Then you would see that the goal or type of the application doesn't matter. E-commerce is not a criteria to decide which patterns can help. Then you'll also be able to decide which ones you need by yourself.

Comment: I would have to agree with bionic. Design patterns are mixed together each serving their own purpose for their own situation. Also remember to keep it simple.